# Using fulltext search in MYSQL with ngram parser enabled is it possible to search for 1 character words with ngram_token_size set to 2?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, full-text-search, planetscale

I am using Planetscale which has a pretty big limitation in that you can't edit the mysql configuration so I cannot set ngram_token_size which defaults to 2. The problem with this is I need to use this for logographic languages such as Chinese which requires I be able to search for singular characters e.g. 你

Any suggestions on how I can get around this limitation.

I have 11 million rows in my database.

My only thought is I could pad every character in my database with a useless unicode character and then in the app code I format the search in the same way and parse the results to remove the useless unicode character.

The only issue with this is I will double my current database size (only 1.8Gb at the moment).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't a 1-char word "a" match two things: `a ` and ` a` ?